# How can I return all Solera Users in my index method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've created an API called api/v1/solera_users, and controller solera_users_controller.rb in my controllers. I have a method index and I want to return all the solera user's there, how I can do that and check all the solera user's in my console?

Here is my route:

```
namespace :api do
  namespace :v1 do
    resources :solera_users
  end
end
```

Here is my controller:

```
module Api
    module V1
      class SoleraUsersController < ApplicationController
        def index
           @users = User.solera_users
        end
      end
    end
end
```

Comment: is solera user is a database table? or is there any relation of user with solera users? Also, do you want to view users in rails console or browser console?

Comment: Yes, Solera is a service and users who got registered on my app through solera are considered as solera users, and i want to view solera users on my console

Comment: on the browser console or rails console?

Comment: @NN796 how i can return them, i just simply want the syntax like if i had users and tables n all like exactly you have said i can return users in my index, in same way m just asking how i can return solera users i mean what would be the syntax in my index?

Comment: @NN796 rails console

Comment: @NN796 It's giving me an error in rails console, didn't i have to access it like, User.solera_users??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will help you (considering you have a model and database table of `solera_users`)

```
def index
  @users = User.solera_users
end
```

In your rails console:

```
users = User.solera_users
users.count
users.first
users.first.email
users.last
```

This will help you in finding more [active record methods](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html)

Comment: https://www.online-convert.com/downloadFile/d084238d-58f4-4e6e-be30-879630614970/Screenshot+from+2019-07-08+11-36-02

Comment: visit the link i have added a screenshot

Comment: I think you don't have `SoleraUser` table in the database, my answer assumed that you have a database table `SoleraUser`. 
You need to provide more information about your question. Are you using a third party service to fetch users? Are you storing these fetched users in your database if yes then what is the name of the database table are you using?
Also, please share the link of the third party service.

Comment: can you run this in your rails console:
`User.solera_users`
`User.solera_users.count`

Comment: like if i run User.solera_users it'll give me this,                                                          User Load (1.0ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE ("users"."solera_uuid" IS NOT NULL) LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 11]]
 => #<ActiveRecord::Relation []>

Comment: and if i run User.solera_users.count it gives me zero, that means i dont have any solera user?

Comment: @usmanbhawal this means you don't have any solera user in your database.

Comment: All else is fine? like syntax for index is ok? i have to return solera users like that?

Answer (score 0):

Try generating a fresh model with or you can choose a different name like only **users**

```
rails g model solera_user name:string
rake db:migrate
rails c
```

last command will open the rails console and add some data into the table

```
SoleraUser.create(name: 'usman')
SoleraUser.all
```

If this works please let me know for further help with your API.

Comment: did you run rake db:migrate